# Como fazer uma configuração remota do Sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Boa tarde pessoal, preciso desenvolver um sistema em C# que necessita utilizar a mesma base de dados em tres computadores distintos, para isso preciso permitir que meu SQL Server 2008 R2 permita a conexão remota com o computador que localizará a base de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você instala o SQL Server junto do banco é instalado o `SQL Server Configuration Manager` nele estão os serviços instalados referentes ao banco.
Com o botão direito você precisa habilitar o protocolo TCP/IP e o Named Pipes.
Depois disso é só reiniciar os serviços e o SQL aceitará conexões remotas.

Comment: Já consegui configurar a configuração remota, gratos pela inteção Krismostre